# Cross reference while defining FK and children relationships SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, relationship, alembic

```
Class Bed
   id
Class Guest
    id
    bed_assignments = relationship(

          primaryjoin=(
              "and_(Guest.id"
              "==foreign(BedAssignment.guest_id),"
              "BedAssignment.bed_status=='occupied')"
         ),

)

Class BedAssignment
    FK Guest
    FK Bed
```

each class is in a file and referencing Guest in BedAssignment class for the FK purpose next to referencing BedAssignment for relationship purpose creates a cross reference.

I tried using text version of FK or relationship referencing , similar to:
`Column(Integer, ForeignKey("bed.id")`
But it seems like a workaround as it stops alembic scripts generation that errors looking for reference.

How the cross reference be solved in this case of relationship model?

Comment: Does my answer solve your concern @Azuz ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your relationship is from an association table + has secondary join specifications, construct your relationship as follows:

```py
bed_assignments = relationship(
    "Bed", #class name of the table
    secondary = "BedAssignment", #table name of the association table
    # Consider using exact tablenames for your join statement...
    primaryjoin = """and_(
        Guest.id==BedAssignment.guest_id,
        BedAssignment.bed_status=='occupied'
    )""",
    backref=backref("Bed", lazy="dynamic"), # if you want the relationship to be observable on the other class... (Guests as children of Beds)
    lazy='dynamic', #only load as needed
    post_update=True, # this allows updating of dependent rows without collisions or cyclical dependencies 
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Yaakov! I needed to reference BedAssignment in guest and vice versa for interpretting relationship classes. I was missing the fact that I could reference classes in the _init_.py in models folder which makes my question answered in other threads.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Also, `backref` would only require the relationship to be declared once. @Azuz

Comment: Also, consider accepting this answer if it solves your Q